# Opencart Folder structure

Tags: opencart2.x

Hi i am unable to get brief idea on the folder structure of opencart , I am using Opencart 2.2.0.0 and each time when i wanted to change anything on website i have to look at each file and i have to modify it accordingly , Sometimes i am unable to find the files related to the page which i am looking for .I have tried search using class names even that won't worked out properly . And when i looked at some forums for few answers there the path for a specific file is different and in my version it is located in some other path , so can anybody suggest how to understand this folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will guide you
http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/developer/module/
There are Two mane [image]if still there is some issue then you can contact back i will be there to help you